# How to handle JWT and App Secrets in a prebuilt docker environment

Tags: docker, shopware6

We are pre building the Shopware 6 code (composer install, storefront + admin build), but not the theme build and copy it into a docker container.

What is the best way to generate or supply the JWT secrets when running such a prebuilt container.

Normally we would do a

```
bin/console secrets:generate-keys
bin/console system:generate-jwt-secret
```

on the first installation.

But can this secrets also be kept in an ENV variable to avoid the need for a persitent `/var` volume?

Comment: Can you find out where those secrets are saved? Maybe just build a script which reads a secret from env and saves it to the appropriate place at runtime?

Comment: Yes this would be an option. Wondering also if they have to be persistent or it's okay to regenerate them on each deploy.

Comment: If the jwt secret is regenerated on each deploy that will probably invalidate all existing admin sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can override secrets locally as [described here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html#local-secrets-overriding-secrets-locally).

So in theory:

- Run `secrets:generate-keys` to generate keys once.
- Run `secrets:decrypt-to-local` to get the secrets added to your `env` file.
- Run `secrets:encrypt-from-local` on deployment to set secrets from your `env` your file.

Comment: The second command prints `0 secrets found in the vault.` - I am also wondering if that covers the JWT secret?